# Is there a short way to list CSS3 keyframes with vendor prefixes?

Tags: css, css-animations

At the moment I have to list all variations:

```
@-webkit-keyframes show {
    from { background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0); }
    to { background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8); }
}

@-moz-keyframes show {
    from { background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0); }
    to { background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8); }
}

[…]
```

You get the idea. Is there any way to write this shorter? Something like this that is not breaking it:

```
@-webkit-keyframes show, @-moz-keyframes show {}
```

Comment: At least for selectors, the rule is that if any of the selectors for a give rule is invalid, then the entire rule has to be dropped - [reference](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#grouping). I would guess the same rule applies here. Since webkit browsers wouldn't see `@-moz...` as valid, it would drop the whole thing, and vice versa.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not natively in CSS but you can accomplish this by using a `CSS` preprocessor, for example [LESS](http://lesscss.org/) which supports the concept of "mixins" to remove some duplication.

More info can be found [here](http://radiatingstar.com/css-keyframes-animations-with-less), specifically the example from the article:

```
@-webkit-keyframes some-animation {.mixi-frames;}
@-moz-keyframes some-animation {.mixi-frames;}

.mixi-frames () {
    from {width: 254px;}
    to {width: 512px;}
}
```

Comment: Yeah, I already thought of *LESS* as the only way to accomplish this.

Comment: Would have been useful to mention that!

Comment: True that. Sorry. I was looking for a native solution and that you answered with your first sentence. So: Thanks. :)

Answer (score 2):

As stated in the accepted answer, mixins in CSS preprocessors have been state of the art to solve this problem some time ago.

But luckily times change and tools get better and better. Frameworks like [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/) switched to tools like [autoprefixer](https://github.com/ai/autoprefixer#browsers) which add vendor prefixes automagically to your css. This way you don't need to think a single second about vendor prefixes anymore and still you stay up-to-date.

Autoprefixer uses data from [caniuse.com](http://caniuse.com/) to keep itself up-to-date and you just need to specify which browsers you want to support and you don't need to care anymore. If you haven't switched to [Grunt](http://gruntjs.com/) task automation yet, now it's time to give it a try, as there is a [grunt-autoprefixer](https://www.npmjs.org/package/grunt-autoprefixer) task available, too.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your requirement, a library such as https://github.com/jQueryKeyframes/jQuery.Keyframes can also accomplish automatic prefixing by managing the keyframe syntax for you.