# css3 rotate not working in IE9 and Firefox

Tags: css, css-transforms

Im trying to get this code to work in IE9 and Firefox. It works perfectly fine in chrome

http://jsfiddle.net/THSdP/1/

```css
@-webkit-keyframes spin {  
    from {  
        transform: rotate(0deg);
        -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
        -ms-transform: rotate(0deg);
    }  
    to {
        transform: rotate(360deg);
        -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg); 
        -ms-transform: rotate(360deg);
        }  
    }
#rsSpinner{
        -webkit-animation-name: spin;  
        -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;  
        -webkit-animation-timing-function: linear;  
        -webkit-animation-duration: 40s;
    }
```

The code only shows the code for Chrome, and it works in there, but I cant seem to get the other prefix sets to work in IE and Firefox.

Comment: At least for Firefox you're missing, what you did for `-webkit-`, [see](http://jsfiddle.net/AChEC/). You can't combine vendor prefixes in key frame animations - you have to list them all separately, [see](http://stackoverflow.com/q/15364081/1456376). Which IE version are you testing?

Comment: I was testing in ie9.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You haven't defined the animation function for firefox, only for `webkit` and `ms`. That's why it's not working in Firefox and IE.

```
@-moz-keyframes spin {
    from {
        -moz-transform: rotate(0deg);
    }
    to {
        -moz-transform: rotate(360deg);
    }
}
```

Another advice is to put the prefix free at the bottom of the definition.

Here is the working code: http://jsfiddle.net/THSdP/5/

Comment: Thanks for this :D it works in firefox, but unfortunately, it does not work in IE.

Comment: Which version of IE have you tried? It's working for me in IE10

Comment: Im using ie9.

someone told me to add this.

    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Matrix(sizingMethod='auto expand', M11=0.7071067811865476, M12=-0.7071067811865475, M21=0.7071067811865475, M22=0.7071067811865476); /* IE6,IE7 */
    -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Matrix(SizingMethod='auto expand', M11=0.7071067811865476, M12=-0.7071067811865475, M21=0.7071067811865475, M22=0.7071067811865476)"; /* IE8 */

where exactly would I put this?

Comment: CSS3 animation doesn't work natively on IE9, you have to use Javascript fallback if you wish to use the keyframes in IE9

Answer (score 1):

Add this for IE

```
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Matrix(sizingMethod='auto expand', M11=0.7071067811865476, M12=-0.7071067811865475, M21=0.7071067811865475, M22=0.7071067811865476); /* IE6,IE7 */
-ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Matrix(SizingMethod='auto expand', M11=0.7071067811865476, M12=-0.7071067811865475, M21=0.7071067811865475, M22=0.7071067811865476)"; /* IE8 */
```

Comment: Fantastic. Where exactly do I add this?

Comment: Add it in ur css on that rotating element

Comment: One more issue I am having. When I add that, it just rotates the image 90degrees but does not continue the animation. Here is a fiddle for it.

http://jsfiddle.net/THSdP/7/

Comment: Im trying right now to get it to work. It just rotated the image 90degrees.